# Disable SwipeRefreshLayout when the ScrollView is not on the top

Tags: android, scrollview, landscape, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `Fragment` which has a `ScrollView` and a `SwipeRefreshLayout`. I want to disable the `SwipeRefreshLayout` when the `ScrollView` is not on the top, so the user can scroll again on the top of the `Fragment`. I tried to create a custom `ScrollView` and override the `onScrollChanged` method like this

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
    int d = view.getBottom();
    d -= (getHeight() + getScrollY());
    if (d <= 0) {
        // bottom
    } else if (getScrollY() <= 0) {
        // top
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }
}
```

This works fine on portrait mode, but not on landscape mode. I tried also to check if the `getScrollX() <= 0` but it didn't work.

Comment: How can user trigger refresh if they're not on the top of `ScrollView`?

Comment: He goes back to the top and swipes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `NestedScrollView`.

This is used when there is a need for a scrolling view inside another scrolling view.